# handlebars helper's parameter is not bound

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

```
<span class="badge badge-inverse">{{kudosReceivedNum user.kudoReceiveds}}</span>

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'kudosReceivedNum', (kudos, options) ->
  kudosTotal = 0
  if kudos
    kudos.forEach (item) ->
      kudosTotal += item.get 'value'

    kudosTotal
```

ApplicationRoute:

```
newKudo = Sks.KudoReceived.createRecord value: kudoNum, comment: kudoComment
user.get('kudoReceiveds').pushObject(newKudo)
```

It only works when I do a refresh or go from another view.

Comment: Hum, I think the problem here is that user.kudoReceiveds is really the same. I don't know how to bind the helper against user.kudoReceiveds.@each, which is I think what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Bound helpers actually take an additional option which are additional dependent keys. For arrays you need to specify `@each` as a dependency. Off the top of my head this would look like:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'kudosReceivedNum', ((kudos, options) ->
  kudosTotal = 0
  if kudos
    kudos.forEach (item) ->
      kudosTotal += item.get 'value'

    kudosTotal), '@each'
```

Comment: I fell back to a computed property on the user model. I think that the helper would be much helpful if I generated some DOM element which I don't do at the moment. Anyway I'd like to thank you for the tip as I didn't know it. Tomorrow I'll show you my solution.